# Cartography constraints with TopLayoutGuide

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, cartography

I have a view which I want to look like this:

```
|---------------|
|               | <- navBar
|---------------|
|               | <- topView
|---------------|
|               |
|               |
|               |
|---------------|
```

Everything I want is to stick topView.top to navBar.bottom. I've decided to go with Cartography and implemented following code (trying to stick to MVC ofc):

In my `UIViewController` subclass:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    aView?.topLayoutGuide = self.topLayoutGuide // where aView is my subclass of UIView, inserted in loadView method
}
```

In my `UIView` subclass:

```
var topLayoutGuide: UILayoutSupport?

override func updateConstraints() {
    var constraint = NSLayoutConstraint?()
    layout(topView) { (topView) in
        constraint = topView.top == topView.superview!.top
    }
    topView.superview!.removeConstraint(constraint!)

    layout(topView) { topView in
        topView.top == topView.superview!.top + (self.topLayoutGuide?.length ?? 0)
        topView.height == 67
        topView.left == topView.superview!.left
        topView.width == topView.superview!.width
    }

    super.updateConstraints()
}
```

The problem is that I receive following logs and I have no idea how to fix it:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
[...]
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe6a64e4800 V:|-(64)-[UIView:0x7fe6a6505d80]   (Names: '|':MyApp.MyView:0x7fe6a360d4c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe6a3538a80 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fe6a6505d80]   (Names: '|':MyApp.MyView:0x7fe6a360d4c0 )>"
)
```

Seems I need some help. How to do it properly? I don't want to implement constraints in `UIViewController` and I don't want to use `Storyboards`.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution: create a reference to that particular `NSLayoutConstraint`, and update its `constant`:

```
var topLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func updateConstraints() { 
    layout(topView) { topView in
        topLayoutConstraint = topView.top == topView.superview!.top
        topView.height == 67
        topView.left == topView.superview!.left
        topView.width == topView.superview!.width
    }

    super.updateConstraints()
}
```

... then later, you can adjust the constant of that NSLayoutConstraint like so:

```
topLayoutConstraint.constant = 50
```

---

The only question that's left is - when do you update the `topLayoutConstraint`? One solution is to create a protocol, `MyViewInterface`:

```
protocol MyViewInterface: class {
    var topLayoutGuideLength: CGFloat { get set }
}
```

Then, in our `UIView`, when that `topLayoutGuideLength` property is changed, we adjust the `constant` of our `NSLayoutConstraint`:

```
public class MyView: UIView, MyViewInterface {
    public var topLayoutGuideLength: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            topLayoutConstraint.constant = topLayoutGuideLength
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, in our `UIViewController` (where our `topLayoutGuide` lives):

```
public class myViewController: UIViewController {

    private var myView: MyView

    // ...

    public override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        myView.topLayoutGuideLength = topLayoutGuide.length
    }
}
```

The end result? Whenever `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is triggered on our `UIViewController`, our `myView`'s `topLayoutGuideLength` property is updated, which triggers a change in that `topLayoutConstraint`'s `constant`.

Comment: I've just resigned temporary from `autolayout`s and currently i'm setting the frames in `layoutSubviews` - this way there is no problem with `topLayoutGuide`. I can't test your solution, but I've tried something similar without result. I'm accepting this answer as it may be the proper solution ;).

Comment: Makes sense to me! I figured this question was a bit stale, but I was working on this same problem yesterday, came across your question, and the above code is what I used to handle it. Thanks for accepting! :)

Answer (score 1):

Another lack of documentation from cartography...

I came across `topLayoutGuideCartography` and `bottomLayoutGuideCartography` properties as a `UIViewController` extension in Cartography. Using them could give you the desired output without overriding `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

You can simply use this property to anchor your view's top.

```
override func updateConstraints() { 
    layout(topView) { topView in
       topView.top == topLayoutGuideCartography
       topView.height == 67
       topView.left == topView.superview!.left
       topView.width == topView.superview!.width
    }

    super.updateConstraints()
}
```

Comment: It seems like a property of the view controller, what I've excluded as an answer in my question, am I right? Please read the question to the end.

Comment: Also, I can't see the difference between `topLayoutGuide` and `topLayoutGuideCartography`. They seem to be the same? Another thing is that I don't think you're right about overriding `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, as it is done to pass the value to the view, what you skip. And I want it in the view, so it's MVC or MVVM.

Comment: @Vive Normally you can't pass `topLayoutGuide` to `anyView.top` since they are not matching types. `topLayoutGuideCartography` is just a proxy.

Also overriding `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is not necessary all the times. It might be because of the way I have written them. I am not updating them in `updateConstraints` as you do. Because the documentation itself also suggests to update them whenever needed. Everything is happening in my viewDidLoad here. This is a VC case as you can see. Might be different in View case.

Comment: Of course you can pass it. You just declare `var topLayoutGuide: UILayoutSupport?` in the view and assign the value of `topLayoutGuide` in the VC. But I don't like this approach, as it's not MVC, MVVM nor any other proper pattern. I understand that worked for you, but in my question it's clearly stated: "I don't want to implement constraints in UIViewController". Anyway, nice finding with that `topLayoutGuideCartography`. It may be useful for people (I don't use this library any more).